# Sending information an email using the On Insert macro

Tags: sharepoint-email

I am pretty new to using MS Access and Sharepoint etc, so your help is greatly appreciated.

I have setup a basic system on Access that allows you to log a technical support ticket on Sharepoint Web App.

When a new ticket is added to the system I have it setup to send an email. However I would like the body of email to contain the Ticket Number, which is Field Name 'ID'.

For example:

> To: My email address
>
> Cc:
>
> Bcc:
>
> Subject: Ticket Number: [ID] has been added to the system.
>
> Body: Please review ticket Number: [ID]

I have searched the net and found lots of information about using `SetLocalVar` etc but I am struggling to understand it.

Comment: Hi All, I have got this working now after setting the LocalVar for Ticket Number and using using the following Syntax in the Subject: =Concat("Ticket Number ",[varTicketID],"has been added to the system")

Answer (score 0):

I have got this working now after setting the LocalVar

SetLocalVar

Name: varTicketID

Expression: = [ID]

for Ticket Number and using the following Syntax in the Subject:

=Concat("Ticket Number ",[varTicketID],"has been added to the system") –